# Как сделать, чтобы в TabBarController иконки отображались со своими цветами?

Tags: ios, swift

У меня иконки для таб бара в PNG формате и там уже заданы нужные мне цвета. Но когда я назначаю эти иконки на итемы для таб бара, то xcode берёт только их альфаканал, а цвета подставляет свои. По умолчанию цвет серый. У меня цвет самого таб бара тёмнобирюзовый и серый цвет на нём смотрится "вырви глаз".

Есть ли простой способ задать режим, чтобы отображались цвета изображения, а не цвета по умолчанию? Что-то я не могу найти подходящий пример. Везде какие-то сложные способы.

В конце концов, хотя бы подскажите как задать цвет не выделенной иконки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляете картинку в `Assets.xcassets` (Images или как назвали). Задаете картинке свойство `Render As Original Image`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подставляете эту картинку для невыделенного состояния:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаете результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чуть позже попробую, как будет мак доступен. Но заранее спасибо!

Comment: Да, всё сработало! Огромное спасибо!